# PHP Select de forma aleatória

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho esse script, que precisei incluir um select de forma aleatória.

```html
<?php
$sql_veiculos = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT ma.categoria, m.modelo, m.versao, m.ano, m.motor, t.transmissao, m.portas, c.combustivel, m.cor, m.km, m.carroceria, m.condicoes, m.descricao, m.visivel, m.placa, m.destaque, m.id, ma.slug, m.slug, m.id, m.valor FROM tb_modelos m LEFT JOIN tb_categorias AS ma ON (m.marca = ma.id) LEFT JOIN tb_transmissao AS t ON (m.transmissao = t.id) LEFT JOIN tb_combustiveis AS c ON (m.combustivel = c.id) WHERE m.visivel = 'S' ORDER BY m.destaque DESC, m.data_cadastro, RAND() DESC LIMIT $limite") or die(mysqli_error($config));  
?>
```

O RAND(), neste caso, está deixando o select aleatório, esta parte está correta.
Mas há mais itens em destaque no banco de dados.

Seria possível fazer a leitura de todos os itens em destaque, exibir de forma aleatória, limitando pela quantidade determinada?

Comment: sim é possível, pode ler todos os registros, por num array e sortear aleatoriamente o que quer exibir

Comment: O que a sua consulta está retornando? Ela já não ordena os destaques primeiro e retorna o LIMIT definido?

Comment: Sim, exato! Mas ele somente ordena e retorna os itens definidos no LIMIT. Por exemplo, há 30 itens marcados como visíveis no banco de dados, mas somente 10 podem ser exibidos. Esse sql, somente ordena os 10 mais recentes. A dúvida surgiu se seria possível ler todos os registros marcados como destaque, e ficar exibindo eles de forma aleatória, pelo limite definido.
Vou tentar colocar em um array.